# Не работает код с SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать мини приложение для регулировки яркости подсветки экрана.

Добавил в манифест строку как было в примере:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Однако, при выполнении следующей строки, приложение падает и, как я понял из лога, вышеуказанная строка не работает

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,i);
```

Ошибка:

> java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.songodv.light was not granted
>   this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.

Comment: Вероятней всего, тут дело не в AS3, а в версии вашего API. Попробуйте использовать requestPermissions()

Answer (score 1):

В Api Level 23 были введены три категории permissions:

1. Normal;
2. Dangerous;
3. Special (их два: `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` и `WRITE_SETTINGS`).

Для первой группы достаточно записи в манифесте, для второй -- необходимо запросить разрешение в рантайме, для третьей -- помимо записи в манифесте нужно еще и запросить разрешение в рантайме при помощи открытия экрана конфигурации.

Для того, чтобы использовать `WRITE_SETTINGS` на Api Level 23+, нужно:

1. Объявить в манифесте:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
   ```
2. Вызвать `Settings.System.canWrite()`. Если метод возвратит `false`, то необходимо перенаправить юзера на экран настроек, дабы он дал соответствующее разрешение:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, за подробный ответ! Попробую